# adding project to github repository

Tags: git, github

when i would like to add my project to the repository I had created in github I failed by this kind of error please someone help me to fix it :

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/.gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/package-lock.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/public/index.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/public/manifest.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/public/robots.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/src/App.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/src/index.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/src/index.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/src/reportWebVitals.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: 'myshop/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

Comment: Seems like you accidentally made two git repos inside eachother

Comment: yes that's exactly my friend.so how can i fix it.i try to delete the second one but I couldn't.

Comment: Delete the `.git` folder inside the /myshop folder

Comment: sorry but i didn't found git folder inside myshop folder

Comment: It's named `.git`, but it's often hidden since it starts with a `.`. You can delete it anyway

Comment: do you mean .gitignore file

Comment: No, the `.git` folder. It's different

Comment: Try to show hidden items in your file explorer. Select the view tab and check the "hidden items"-box.